# Error with file upload as base64 encoded string

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to receive an image from an android device, which is sending an image as a Base64 encoded string. This is my controller action code:

```
public function  Upload()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $dir= APP.'outsidefiles'; //chane directory for cloud
        $fill = $this->request->data['File'] ;
        $data = base64_decode($fill);
        $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
        if ($im !== false)
        {
            $nam ='mypic.png';
            move_uploaded_file($im['tmp_name'],$dir.DS.time().$nam);
        }

        //$dir= APP . 'outsidefiles';

        //  $this->request->data['Grade']['Fila']= $File;
        $this->Grade->create();
        if ($this->Grade->save($this->request->data))
        {

            $return = array(
                'Response' =>'1',
                'Body' => 'Data Saved');
            return new CakeResponse(array('body' => json_encode($return, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)));

        }
        else
        {
            $return = array(
                'Response' =>'0',
                'Body' => 'Data not saved');
            return new CakeResponse(array('body' => json_encode($return, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)));
        }
    }
}
```

However the image is not created in the destination folder - what is the error?

Comment: Please read the [help] pages.  You need to explain in more detail what exactly _is_ happening and what troubleshooting you've already done.

Comment: @JimGarrison The image is not moved into the folder on the server and also when i try to display it, an empty page appears(no image displayed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### move uploaded file is for moving *uploaded files*

This will not work:

```
move_uploaded_file("I am not a file upload" , "/put/file/here/path.png");
```

It won't work even if the first argument points at a file because, [as stated in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php):

> If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.

This prevents this kind of naïve attack from working:

```
// User input is not safe, it could be e.g.:
$_FILES['example']['tmp_name'] = '/etc/passwd'; 
...
move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES['example']['tmp_name'], 
    "/web/accessible/location/now-public.txt"
);
```

### image create from string does not return an array

This also won't work:

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
$im['tmp_name']; <-
```

As, the return value from this function [is an image resource, not an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php). `tmp_name` related to file uploads - there is no actual file upload if it is being submitted as a base64 encoded string; *it's just a string*.

### To upload a base64 encoded string means only creating a file

The logical steps required are not related to file uploads at all, only writing a binary string to a file i.e.:

```
$data = base64_decode($fill);
file_put_contents('/tmp/pic.png', $data);
```